# Why do i need to use the $ when i have a parameter object?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I was recently experimenting in jquery and wanted to learn how to send an object from a textbox to my script. example:

```
   <asp: textbox id="box1" onchange="javascript: test(this);" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Script:

```
function test(obj){

if(parseInt(obj.val())){
// code
}
}
```

This did not work! I later found that I had to use the "$" sign to make this work, like this:

$(obj).val()

Why? I figured that I already have the object I need in the parameter so why do I need to select it again?

thanks!

Comment: Just a note, since this is a text input, you can access it's value directly with `obj.value`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`val` is a method of a jQuery collection, which is what is returned when you pass a selector or DOMElement object to `$`. To access the value without jQuery, use the `value` property exposed by the DOM.

```
function test(obj){

    if(parseInt(obj.value){
    // code
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the pointer to how to do it without using jQuery. However, there is a LOT of functionality (not directly relevant to the question) that does not directly translate to plain javascript calls.

Comment: talk about fast answers! thanks alot! very helpfull!
If you by any chance have a link where i can read about this and other stuff i would deeply appreciate it. (others than jquery.com)

Comment: @krillgar I was just revising some of my old answers, and came across your comment. Regarding this: *"However, there is a LOT of functionality (not directly relevant to the question) that does not directly translate to plain javascript calls."*, I'm not sure what you mean. The jQuery library *is* a collection of plain old javascript calls. What functionality are you speaking of?

Comment: I imagine that I was referring to the ease of jQuery method calls that include validation and multi-browser support, versus the repetition of that. That could be replicated in your own code, but it is sufficiently tested before release in jQuery's library to work in 99% of browsers. But, it has been a while since my comment. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `this` that you send into the function (and use in the function as `obj`) is just a javascript object. The `$()` turns it into a jQuery object, which adds all of the extra functionality to the object that jQuery provides (including the `val()` method).

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a DOM element.

`$(this)` is a jQuery object.

You can only call `jQuery` methods on `jQuery` objects.

Answer (score 0):

$ is a **shortcut** to [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). So, to access the functions provided by the jQuery library you need to "convert" an **Javascript object** to a **jQuery Object**.